# Is there a unique natural transformation of functors $t : F \to F'$ such that $t(U) = T(\text{Id}_F(U))$?

Tags: category-theory, functors, yoneda-lemma

Let $C, D$ be categories, $F$ and $F'$ covariant functors from $C$
to $D$.

For any natural transformation of bifunctors $T : \hom_D(−, F(−)) \to
\hom_D(−, F'(−))$ there is a unique natural transformation of functors $t :
F \to F'$ such that $t(U) = T(\text{Id}_F(U))$.

I tried using Yoneda to see the naturality of $t$, but it didn't work here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let $J: A\to B$ be a fully faithful functor.
> Then, for any category $E$, the functor $J_*: Fun(E,A)\to Fun(E,B), G\mapsto J\circ G$ is also fully faithful.

It's a very important lemma, which is not too hard to prove. Be careful though, in trying to prove it, that the same lemma does *not* hold if you replace "fully faithful" by "full", so to prove fullness you will need to use fully faithfulness of $J$.

Then consider $y: D\to Fun(D^{op},Set)$ the Yoneda embedding. By the Yoneda lemma, it is fully faithful, by the lemma, $y_* : Fun(C,D)\to Fun(C,Fun(D^{op},Set))$ is also fully faithful.

Howevern $Fun(C,Fun(D^{op},Set))\cong Fun(C\times D^{op},Set)$, so your functors $\hom_D(-,F(-)) $ and $\hom_D(-,F'(-))$ live in this category, more specifically they can be written as $y_*(F)$ and $y_*(F')$ respectively.

It follows that $T: y_*F\to y_*F'$ can be written as $y_*t$ for some $t: F\to F'$, which is automatically natural (and unique).

Now note that for a fixed $U\in C$, $T_{(-,U)}$ is a natural transformation $\hom_D(-,F(U))\to \hom_D(-,F'(U))$ induced in fact by $t_U$. The Yoneda lemma automatically implies that it must be satisfy $t_U= T_{(F(U),U)}(id_{F(U)})$.

In particular this definition of $t$ makes it natural (if that's what you were worried about), and of course unique (because well it gives a fixed definition of $t$) - and (to my mind, more importantly) an antecedent of $T$ through $y_*$.

Comment: I am grateful for your writing so much! thank you!

Comment: quick question about the last paragraph: why t is natural?

Comment: $t$ is an arrow in $Fun(C,D)$, therefore it's natural

Comment: thank you, this makes sense. if we use Yoneda Lemma only, like what you did in the last two paragraph, and ignore the previous paragraphs for now, why is t natural? it merely a elemennt from $hom(F(U), F'(U))$,...

Comment: I found lemma 4.1.3 from here http://www.math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/context.pdf. But it applies to adjoint functor case, seems it doesn't apply here.   this is my last question. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: why would we ignore them ? If you don't want to use them for some reason, you can prove the naturality of $t$ by using the fact that $T$ is natural

Comment: ok thank you!!!